# MongoDB save with a collection type - another way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

First time using mongodb.
I am using node.js and mongojs on the server side. A little confused. The reversal of db.save is find, and I'd like to be able to do something similar to:

```
 db.furni.find( db.furni_types.chair, db.furni_types.chair.plastic );
```

Current setup:

```
// Chair types
db.furni_types.save({ type: "chair", material: "wood" });
db.furni_types.save({ type: "chair", material: "plastic" });
db.furni_types.save({ type: "chair", material: "beanbag" });

// other furni types
db.furni_types.save({ type: "bed", material: "silk" });
db.furni_types.save({ type: "table", effect: "glass" });


db.furni.save({id: "13626450", name: "ComfyMan", type: "chair", material: "wood", description: "The most comfortable chair in extistence."});
```

A few questions:

Am I going about this the right way or what?

Would the array found in db.furni.save(type: "chair", material: "wood") sufficient if I wanted to use these as objects later?

What if I wanted to do something like:

```
 db.furni.save( name: "Super Comfort", db.furni_types.chair, db.furni_types.chair.wood );
```

Would the above work?

Comment: What's wrong with `db.furni.find( type:"chair", material:"plastic")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not the right way... First off it is very much a RDBMS way of thinking, (relational database...).  Secondly if you want to be able to do something like this:

```
db.furni.find( db.furni_types.chair, db.furni_types.chair.plastic );
```

Then it would just be:

```
db.furni.find({type: "chair", material:"plastic"});
```

Note that what you are passing into find is an object, so you cannot just expect to pass strings or something from other variables in a comma separated format, let alone think that you can just reference your types model that way (db.furni_types != a direct accessor at the data in the database, its an interface upon which you have to "find").

So just looking at what you have posted and what I suggest, you will also see that if you have to type "chair" in both, and "plastic" in both regardless, what value do you expect to gain from your proposed approach?

Comment: You're absolutely right now that I think about it. I guess I was just getting caught up in trying to think about the future of the project. In the future, I'd like to make things happen based on a certain criteria. Another thing was that I wasn't really separating the database things and javascript things. The two work very closely with one another but not that close.

Comment: @LeviRoberts  - You might also like mongoose in case you've not already looked at it.  It will help with a lot of syntactic sugar for things like embedding and linking of documents, and might provide more of the syntax sugar that you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I did look into mongoose a little. Off the top of my head I can't remember why I chose not to go with it. I do believe it was because of the learning curve. After using mongojs, I find it to be more like mongo client commands so was very easy to pick up.